# How to use constant in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How i can use constant in angular, i want to attach a constant value via factory. Please check the following code

/* **Factory which attach the constant in app module** */

```
'use strict';
define(['app'], function (app) {
    var traslationParams = ['$resource'];

    var translationFactory = function (resource) {
        return {
            attachTranslator: function (language) {
                var languageFilePath = applicationUrl.clientUrl + '/translation/translation_' + language + '.json';
                resource(languageFilePath).get(function (data) {
                    app.constant('languagePack', data); // registering  constant
                });
            }
        }
    }
    translationFactory.$inject = traslationParams;
    app.factory('translationFactory', translationFactory);
});
```

// **I am executing the factory api to register the constant using following code**

```
 app.run([ 'translationFactory',  function ( translationFactory) {

         translationFactory.attachTranslator('da');}]);
```

// **The usage of constant in controller**

```
var companyController = function (languagePack) {

       scope.languagePack = languagePack;
        console.log(languagePack);
}
```

but i am getting an error in my controller

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: languagePackProvider <- languagePack <- companyController
```

Comment: By definition, a constant is supposed to be constant. You're initializing it with the result of a HTTP request, depending on a language parameter. So it's not a constant at all. Constants must be defined before the config phase, just as services and controllers. Once the config phase starts, you can't define constants anymore.

Comment: @JBNizet then what is the other options available to keep a value ,which can be injected across services/controllers

Comment: If it's dynamically obtained, then store it as a field of a service, and inject the service.

Answer (score 0):

Add languagepack as a translationFactory attribute and save the translation output to this attribute. Further reference this attribute through service in the controller.

```
'use strict';
define(['app'], function (app) {
var traslationParams = ['$resource'];

var translationFactory = function (resource) {
    return {
        languagePack: {},
        attachTranslator: function (language) {
            var trans = this;
            var languageFilePath = applicationUrl.clientUrl + '/translation/translation_' + language + '.json';
            resource(languageFilePath).get(function (data) {
                //app.constant('languagePack', data); // registering  constant
trans.languagePack = data
            });
        }
    }
}
translationFactory.$inject = traslationParams;
app.factory('translationFactory', translationFactory);
});



app.run([ 'translationFactory',  function ( translationFactory) {
     translationFactory.attachTranslator('da');}]);



var companyController = function (translationFactory) {
   scope.languagePack = translationFactory.languagePack;
    console.log(scope.languagePack);
}
```